# VueJS xref in <image> withinin SVG without vueloader?

Tags: image, svg, vue.js

This works:

```
<svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
  <image 
    id="img-1" 
    class='svg-image' 
    width="435px" 
    height="590px"
    xlink:href="https://www.somewebsite.com/some_picture.jpg"
  />
</svg>
```

But, `v-bind:xref="finalUrl(store.images[0].url)"` doesn't work.

I've looked through this issue, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/569, and was hoping there was some way to get this functionality without adding webpack/vueloader to this project. Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to `xlink:href` using `v-bind` with object notation like this:

```
<svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
  <image 
    id="img-1" 
    class='svg-image' 
    width="435px" 
    height="590px"
    v-bind="{ 'xlink:href': finalUrl(store.images[0].url) }"
  />
</svg>
```